# DirectX, scaling orthgraphic vertices to world space vertices

Tags: c++, matrix, directx

**Introduction**

---

Let's say I have the following vertices:

```
const VERTEX World::vertices[ 4 ] = {
    { -960.0f, -600.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },    // side 1 screen coordinates centred
    { 960.0f, -600.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
    { -960.0f, 600.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 960.0f, 960.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }
};
```

You may have guessed that 960 * 2 is 1920.. which is the width of my screen and same goes for 600 * 2 being 1200.

These vertices represent a rectangle that will fill up my ENTIRE screen where the origin is in the centre of my screen.

---

**Issue**

---

So up until now, I have been using an Orthographic view without a projection:

```
matView = XMMatrixOrthographicLH( Window::width, Window::height, -1.0, 1.0 );
```

Any matrix that was being sent to the screen was multiplied by matView and it seemed to work great. More specifically, my image; using the above vertices array, fit snugly in my screen and was 1:1 pixels to its original form.

**Unfortunately, I need 3D now**... and I just realised i'm going to need some projection... so I prepared this little puppy:

```
XMVECTOR vecCamPosition = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0 ); // I did try setting z to -100.0f but that didn't work well as I can't scale it back any more... and it's not accurate to the 1:1 pixel I want
XMVECTOR vecCamLookAt = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
XMVECTOR vecCamUp = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
matView = XMMatrixLookAtLH( vecCamPosition, vecCamLookAt, vecCamUp ); 

matProjection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(
    XMConvertToRadians( 45 ),        // the field of view
    Window::width / Window::height,  // aspect ratio
    1.0f,                            // the near view-plane
    100.0f );                        // the far view-plan
```

You may already know what the problem is... but if not, I have just set my field of view to 45 degrees.. this'll make a nice perspective and do 3d stuff great, but my vertices array is no longer going to cut the mustard... **because the fov and screen aspect have been greatly reduced (or increased ) so the vertices are going to be far too huge for the current view I am looking at (see image)**

I was thinking that I need to do some scaling to the output matrix to scale the huge coordinates back down to the respective size my fov and screen aspect is now asking for.

**What must I do to use the vertices array as it is (1:1 pixel ratio to the original image size) while still allowing 3d stuff to happen like have a fly fly around the screen and rotate and go closer and further into the frustrum etc...**

---

**Goal**

---

I'm trying to avoid changing every single objects vertices array to a rough scaled prediction of what the original image would look like in world space.

---

[image]

---

**Some extra info**

---

I just wanted to clarify what kind of matrix operations I am currently doing to the world and then how I render using those changes... so this is me doing some translations on my big old background image:

```
// flipY just turns the textures back around
// worldTranslation is actually the position for the background, so always 0,0,0... as you can see 0.5 was there to make sure I ordered things that were drawn correctly when using orthographic

XMMATRIX worldTranslation = XMMatrixTranslation( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f );
world->constantBuffer.Final = flipY * worldTranslation * matView;

// My thoughts are on this that somehow I need to add a scaling to this matrix... 
// but if I add scaling here... it's going to mean every other game object 
// (players, enemies, pickups) are going to need to be scaled... and really I just want to 
// have to scale the whole lot the once.. right?
```

And finally this Is where it is drawn to the screen:

```
// Background

    d3dDeviceContext->PSSetShaderResources( 0, 1, world->textures[ 0 ].GetAddressOf( ) ); // Set up texture of background
    d3dDeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, world->vertexbuffer.GetAddressOf( ), &stride, &offset ); // Set up vertex buffer (do I need the scaling here?)
    d3dDeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST ); // How the vertices be drawn
    d3dDeviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer( world->indexbuffer.Get( ), DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0 ); // Set up index buffer

    d3dDeviceContext->UpdateSubresource( constantbuffer.Get( ), 0, 0, &world->constantBuffer, 0, 0 ); // set the new values for the constant buffer
    d3dDeviceContext->OMSetBlendState( blendstate.Get( ), 0, 0xffffffff ); // DONT FORGET IF YOU DISABLE THIS AND YOU WANT COLOUR, * BY Color.a!!!
    d3dDeviceContext->DrawIndexed( ARRAYSIZE( world->indices ), 0, 0 ); // draw
```

and then what I have done to apply my matProjection which has supersized all my vertices

```
world->constantBuffer.Final = flipY * worldTranslation * matView * matProjection; // My new lovely projection and view that make everything hugeeeee... I literally see like 1 pixel of the background brah!
```

**Please feel free to take a copy of my game and run it as is (Windows 8 application Visual studio 2013 express project) in the hopes that you can help me out with putting this all into 3D:** https://github.com/jimmyt1988/FlyGame/tree/LeanerFramework/Game

Comment: Can you post the code for rendering the rectangle?  The solution is probably simple, but I'll need code before I throw it out there and look like an idiot when that's not the problem.  I'm looking for how you'd render the rectangle without a perspective matrix and what you'd change to render it with a perspective matrix.

Comment: I hope that's what you needed (added to OP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its me again. Let me try to clear a few things up

**1**

Here is a little screenshot from an editor of mine:
[image]

I have edited in little black boxes to illustrate something. The axis circles you see around the objects are rendered at **exactly** the same size. However, they are rendered through a perspective projection. As you can see, the one on the far left is something like twice as large as the one in the center. This is due purely to the nature of a projection like that. If this is unacceptable, you must use a non-perspective projection.

**2**
The only way it is possible to maintain a `1:1` ratio of screenspace to uv space is to have the object rendered at 1 pixel on screen per 1 pixel on texture. There is nothing more to it than that. However, what you can do is change your texture filter options. Filter options are designs **specifically** for rendering non `1:1` ratios. For example, the code:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Tells opengl: "If you are told to sample a pixel, don't interpolate anything. Just take the nearest value on the texture and paste it on the screen.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

This code, however, does something much better: it interpolates between pixels. I think this may be what you want, if you aren't already doing it.

These pictures (taken from http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/) show this:

Nearest:

[image]

Linear:

[image]

Here is what it comes down to. You request that:

> What must I do to use the vertices array as it is (1:1 pixel ratio to the original image size) while still allowing 3d stuff to happen like have a fly fly around the screen and rotate and go closer and further into the frustrum etc...

What you are requesting is by definition not possible, so you have to look for alternative solutions. I hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Something you said above or here helped me out a bit.... I realised that the real question I want to ask is how to add a projection without mucking up the 1:1 pixel scale of the orthographic view I set up. matView = XMMatrixOrthographicLH( Window::width, Window::height, -1.0, 100.0f );

Comment: Thats what I am trying to say! There is NO WAY to do what you are asking. What you really need to do is get a pixel filter setting to mask the fact that it is not a 1:1 ratio. Look at ANY 3D program, and you will find that the scale is not 1:1. The key is making that ratio look good.

Comment: Cool, well in that case... I might just apply a huge negative scale to my objects vertices to set them back a bit

Comment: Thanks for your time mate. I've learnt a lot and you have helped. I think ill mark this one as done